# GMap.net in wpf custom marker icon

Tags: wpf, marker, gmap.net

I want to use GMAP.NET in WPF
I have add GMap.NET.Core.dll and GMap.NET.WindowsForms.dll as reference to my project.
with help of this [document](http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-beginners-tutorial-maps-markers-polygons-routes-updated-for-vs2015-and-gmap1-7.html) I am using GMAP.Net but in WPF. Now I want to use a a custom icon for my marker but I couldn't find the way.
My Code is as below

```
 gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.BingMapProvider.Instance;
        GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly; 
        gmap.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(35.6960617168288, 51.4005661010742);
        gmap.ShowCenter = false;

        GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.GMapMarker marker = new GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.GMapMarker(new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(35.6960617168288, 51.4005661010742));
        marker.Shape = new Ellipse
        {
            Width = 10,
            Height = 10,
            Stroke = Brushes.Red,
            StrokeThickness = 1.5,
            ToolTip = "This is tooltip",
            Visibility=Visibility.Visible,
            Fill=Brushes.Red,

        };
        gmap.Markers.Add(marker);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use an instance of `Image` as a value for `Shape` property:

```
marker.Shape = new Image
{
    Width = 10,
    Height = 10,
    Source = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri("pack://application:,,,/assets/marker.png"))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After Searching more I found this code which works:

```
 System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImage = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"D:\s.gif");
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.GMapMarker marker2 = new GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation.GMapMarker(new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(35.6960617168288, 51.4005661010742));
        System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        image.Source = bitmapImage;
        marker2.Shape = image;
        gmap.Markers.Add(marker2);
```

This [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d2e6c478-1f52-40e3-bc2f-08fb37b4d5af/cross-threading-error-on-drawing-to-wpf-from-datareceived-event-of-serialport?forum=wpf) helped me.